# Why Laravel Storage Exists function return true but readStream return null

Tags: laravel, digital-ocean

My question is simple, I have a space in Digital Ocean that this function is working fine locally but in my production server is not working why?

I have two functions:

```
$exists = Storage::disk($media->disk)->exists($sourceFile);
$file = Storage::disk($media->disk)->readStream($sourceFile);
```

The file exists return true to me but when I make readStream the file return NULL to me why?

Comment: It seems like it can't read that file.. what kind of file is it?

Comment: It is a simple image.jpeg

Comment: You need to also do something like this `file_put_contents($targetFile, stream_get_contents($file), FILE_APPEND);`